# Merging Neo4j and HBase data using Apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, hbase

I want to merge data from neo4j and hbase. After googling a lot, I decided to do it using Apache Spark (or is there any better way to do this which I missed?). I used [hbase-spark](https://github.com/apache/hbase/tree/master/hbase-spark) and [neo4j-spark connectors](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector) to fetch the data and obtain RDDs.

The thing I want to know is that will joining these two RDDs happen in parallel on different machines in cluster? I understand that I might have to run spark executors on the same machines as hbase's regions (and also that I have to avoid methods like `collect` which fetch all data on spark driver node). The problem is with neo4j. The data gets fetched from neo4j on driver program, right? Then how the joining will happen in parallel? Will spark rdd handle it transparently underneath? Or I will have to do some configuration explicitly? Or I am understanding it all wrong and the whole thing (parallel join on different machines) is simply unachievable?